# How to apply conditions on multiple columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below Pandas dataframe. I want to add a new column called revenue.

Revenue should be 15% of order total for "2. 5 to 19" and 25% of order total for "3. More than 20". and 0 for "1. Less than 5". What can I try with this code?

[image]

I tried the below code but it is giving error:

```
x['Revenue'] = np.where(x['Cost_Buckets'] == "2. 5 to 19",0.15*x['Order_total'],np.where(
    x['Cost_Buckets'] == "3. More than 20",0.25*x['Order_total'],0))
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: You may also need to add some data to your sample code, so that readers can paste it into their code environment and try it for themselves. An image of data is insufficient.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x['Revenue'] = 0
x['Revenue'] = np.where(x['Cost_Buckets'] == "2. 5 to 19",0.15*x['Order_total'], x['Revenue'])
x['Revenue'] = np.where(x['Cost_Buckets'] == "3. More than 20",0.25*x['Order_total'], x['Revenue'])
```

Although three line of codes, but easier to understand